# Why codeIgniter duplicating and appending URL?

Tags: codeigniter, url

When I moved my working CI webapp from my localhost to a webhosting, I encounter a "duplicating and appending URL" problem.

In my localhost, this works (shows the login page): http:**//mylocal/someapp/** --> which will redirect to http:**//mylocal/someapp/index.php/login**

However, after migrating to webhosting, trying to access it like this: http:**//webhosting.com/someapp/**, somehow it automatically appends to be 
http:**//webhosting.com/someapp/%20//webhosting.com/someapp/index.php/login**

My .htaccess contains nothing (works on localhost)

In config.php,

```
$config['base_url']= '';
```

The ***home*** controller which will redirect to the ***login*** controller (then the ***login*** view) looks like this:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
 }

 function index()
 {
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
   {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
     $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
   }
   else
   {
     //If no session, redirect to login page
     redirect('login', 'refresh');
   }
 }

 function logout()
 {
   $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
   session_destroy();
   redirect('home', 'refresh');
 }

}
```

Or maybe some settings in the webhosting that I need to configure?

Answer (score 5):

Use `http://` prefix before base url in  `$config['base_url'];`
    e.g.

```
$config['base_url']=http://localhost/islam;
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question!  Code-only answers [are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274) on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it impossible for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it.  Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['base_url']= '';
```

should contain the base url of your website. i think that's the problem.

should be:

```
$config['base_url']= 'http://yoursite.com/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer my self. Turns out that some webhostings are not treating CI refresh properly.

```
header("Refresh:0;url=...");
```

instead, it only wants this:

```
header("Location: ...");
```

So, I changed **url_helper.php** (system/helpers/url_helper.php line:543), from

```
case 'refresh'
```

to

```
case 'xxxrefresh'
```

so that it always skips the header refresh and only use header location.
I don't know if this the proper solution, but it works on my website.
Test your webhosting characteristics before you migrate your CodeIgniter codes from your local machine.

Hope this helps somebody in the future.

Comment: you should have used redirect('login'); without the 'refresh' parameter, that way the location header will be used by default. Also it is considered bad practice to modify the core. When you'll update the codeigniter to the latest version all your changes will be lost.

Comment: You should have used the `method` parameter in the `redirect` function, setting it to `location`, instead of editing a core class. See here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "duplication problem" with a local insallation. Here is my solution: set your base URL in application/config/config.php, for example:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/';
```

It is important to add the `http://` or `https://` prefix to fix the "duplication problem". Of course, the trailing slash is also necessary.